# How do I pass values between multiple react.js apps running at the same time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have two different React.js apps, App1 and App2, running on different servers, say, localhost:8080 and localhost:8081. The Apps are entirely independent from one another.

I also have a wrapper App, that displays App1 and App2 in the same single-page-application.

What can I do so that my interactions with App1 (e.g. pressing a button, filling in a textbox) sends an event trigger to, or interact in other ways with, App2?

I'm trying to find a way to do this through the wrapper App, and not hard-coding the interaction in App1 and App2, so that it would be easier to scale in the future.

Comment: How are these apps wrapped? By using `<iframe />`?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is passing data between two pages on the same domain. You can achieve this with postMessage.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

If your pages aren't on the same domain you may need to create a websocket server to send messages between the two.

Comment: @sinned My current method is to export the different apps as a bundled js file placed into their respective servers, then the wrapper app accesses these bundled js files and displays them in its own app. I'm just testing things out, so it's a bit of a stupid method, I'm sure. I'm definitely open to change the wrapping process to anything that would work better.

Comment: @Kyle I think the end goal is to allow for communications even on different domains, so I'll look into creating a websocket server. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You can use Firebase. It works are a shared network object with observables. All apps observe the same remote object, and changes are populated across all of them in real time. https://firebase.google.com/